# React - Load/Show current user posts only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, jsx

I want to make a return in React that shows all posts of each user when they're logged in.

The problem is that right now, my code loads all posts of all users and only shows the posts from the current logged in user, but the others posts occupy screen space. I want to remove / not load the non logged in user posts.

I think the problem is that right now I do the verification in the JSX, but I have to do it on the map() function that load the posts, but can't find the solution by myself.

This is my code at the moment:

```
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
  const classes = useStyles()
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))

  return (
    <>
      <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems='stretch' spacing={3}>
        {
          posts.map((post) => (
            <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={4}>
            {(user?.result?.googleId === post?.creator || user?.result?._id === post?.creator) && (
              <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId}/>
            )}
            </Grid>
          ))
        }
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
```

And this is the output example:

[image]

Can someone help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are rendering `Grid` and then checking condition so your `Grid` is taking that space.

You just need to check your condition one line up before rendering `Grid`

Try like below:

```
      {posts.map(
        post =>
          (user?.result?.googleId === post?.creator ||
            user?.result?._id === post?.creator) && (
            <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
          )
      )}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I'm really gratefull, thanks a lot. Now I only have to correct one little error that duplicates my posts. Thanks again!

Comment: I’m happy to help

Comment: Sorry Priyank, one question about the code: if there is no posts from one user, then the first post that the user does gets duplicated on screen and the console shows the following error:

Encountered two children with the same key .Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted.

And if I refresh the page, the duplicated posts gets eliminated from screen and only the correct one appears.
Then for the following posts the code works perfectly. Do you know how can I control that?

Comment: This issue only happens when user add post so maybe in posts array it is storing duplicate? can you check by console logging `posts` array?

Comment: The post array gets duplicated with two elements with the same key, but actually the duplicated element doesn't load into the database and if I refresh the page the duplicated element gets eliminated from the array. Maybe it is a state problem of my code?

Comment: Yes, if it certainly is code related problem. Can you create working demo in https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ so we can take better look?

Comment: And I would recommend to create another question so if I am not around then other can quickly help you out.

Comment: Thanks Priyank, I have managed to fix it. I was setting the current id to null instead to 0, now it works. Thanks for all the help :)